# How can we place the cursor in Chrome Driver address bar and perform Key.Enter events using selenium Web driver using java?

Tags: selenium

I am automating the application using selenium which is enabled with SSO(VIDM) integration which will take my system domain name and password. The moment I hit the application URL, It will process the SSO(VIDM) and displaying the browser pop up with SSL certificate , OK button. I am unable to locate "OK" button as inspect is blocked for that pop up.

Manual Work Around noticed: Able to select that certificate from the pop up with out clicking okay button by placing the cursor in Chrome driver address bar and then perform enter using the system keyboard.[Please see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvqXx.png)

Comment: What exactly are you referring as **Chrome Driver address bar**?

Comment: I have update the problem statement. Could you please check

Answer (score 0):

Add the below chromedriver option to launch specific profile.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Refer to chromedriver page for more information.
[ChromeDriver Capabilities](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

Comment: I should not ignore the certificate. Without certificate selection I can't move further. Below code is I tried but no luck.

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless", "--disable-gpu",
     "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-extenstions");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

Comment: Options 1: Load chrome profile with pre-installed certificate

Comment: Option 2: Loading the certificate in chrome programatically (does this work for you)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am not aware of these suggestioms.please provide solution

Comment: You can install the certificate and use that profile for your tests. Updated the answer to use the profile.